# return function in document.write

Tags: javascript, time

I need return showtime function in document.write to show time 
Please Help Me

Link : [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/oDidOFUs/1/edit)

```
var timerID = null;
var timerRunning = false;
function showtime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var tm = " AM";

    if (hours == 12) { tm = " PM"; }

    if (hours < 12) { tm = " AM"; }

    if (hours > 12) { hours = hours - 12; tm = " PM"; }

    if (hours == 0) { tm = " AM"; hours = 12; }

    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    var timeValue = "" + hours;
    timeValue  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
    timeValue  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
    LocalTimer.innerHTML = timeValue + tm;
    timerID = setTimeout("showtime()",1000);
    timerRunning = true;
}
```

do you need more details for this Question ?

Comment: You can't really return from the function between each iteration.

Comment: Did u mean document.write(showTime()) ?

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Yes but not worked http://jsbin.com/oDidOFUs/1/edit

Comment: @adeneo i`m only cant onload="showtime()" it`s different for me and i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to fix issue of your code and made some changes in your code. I hope this will match your requirement.

```
var timerID = null;
var timerRunning = false;
var LocalTimer = document.getElementById("localTimer");
function showtime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var tm = " AM";

    if (hours == 12) { tm = " PM"; }

    if (hours < 12) { tm = " AM"; }

    if (hours > 12) { hours = hours - 12; tm = " PM"; }

    if (hours === 0) { tm = " AM"; hours = 12; }

    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    var timeValue = "" + hours;
    timeValue  += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
    timeValue  += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
    LocalTimer.innerHTML = timeValue + tm;
  timerID = setTimeout(function(){showtime();},1000);
    timerRunning = true;
}

showtime();
```

Please follow this [link](http://jsbin.com/oDidOFUs/2/) for your updated demo.